# MacBook Pro Crashes When Switching from One Monitor to Two in Closed Clamshell

Tags: macbook-pro, display, crash, kernel-panic

**What I'm working with**

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
- Processor 2.9 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5
- Memory 8GB 1867 MHz DDR3
- Startup is internal HD
- Graphics Intel Iris 6100 1536 MB
- MacOS 12.2

**Situation**

I started using my MacBook Pro in closed clamshell, desktop mode a couple weeks ago. On my desk I have two ASUS VS248H-P monitors where I have two HDMI switches plugged into them. On the other end of the switches is my MBP & a windoze machine (dell) for work. During the day, I normally run my right monitor (SCR2) on my MBP, left monitor (SCR1) on the dell. At the end of my day I would switch SCR1 from my dell to my MBP. Up until a couple days ago, I could flip the switches during the day, here and there, no problem, but all of sudden when I switch from the dell to the MBP on SCR1, (SCR2 has been on the MBP all day) SCR2 would dim but look like it's just hanging in space and is connected, waiting for SCR1 to pickup, and SCR1 would never look like it's making the switch. At this point I'd have to open the MBP and hold the power button down and reboot. I would then be able to work all night w/ both screens and no problems. Power is plugged in. Tried zapping PRAM.

A few things to note, MBP to SCR1 switch is a Thunderbolt to HDMI cable and MBP to SCR2 switch is HDMI. I have no other issues like this and did a clean reformat and reinstall of the MacOS two weeks ago before I set this all up - this screen issue only occurs around 5p when I switch SCR1 to the MBP. Currently plugged into the MBP, aside from the HDMI and Thunderbolt, is an Anker USB 10 port hub (one mouse switch, 4 ext HDs) and another ext HD.

**Problem Details and System Config Report**

```
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000001000c07
 family: 6 model: 61 stepping: 4 microcode: 47
 signature: 0x306d4
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5287U CPU @ 2.90GHz
 7 error-reporting banks
Processor 0: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 2: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 3: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 3, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 1 2
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 4 acks but received 1 after 29882555 loops in 1450000000 ticks
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff801d5d68b7): Machine Check at 0xffffff801d4e957f, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x00007fe659018998, CR3: 0x000000002167c000, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0
RAX: 0xffffff902f054ee4, RBX: 0xffffffd01dc35c90, RCX: 0x00000000ffffffff, RDX: 0x00000000acda7d00
RSP: 0xffffffd0962e3980, RBP: 0xffffffd0962e3a00, RSI: 0xffffffd0962e3a10, RDI: 0xffffe1a55c83a00e
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0xffffffd01dadc830, R11: 0xffffff869574e540
R12: 0xffffffd01dc35c90, R13: 0xffffff902f054ee4, R14: 0xffffffd0962e3a10, R15: 0xffffffd0962e3a10
RFL: 0x0000000000000002, RIP: 0xffffff801d4e957f, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000000
Error code: 0x0000000000000000
 @trap_native.c:168
Panicked task 0xffffff8695163670: 196 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Backtrace (CPU 3), panicked thread: 0xffffff869574e540, Frame : Return Address
0xffffff801d357ac0 : 0xffffff801d485ffd 
0xffffff801d357b10 : 0xffffff801d5e6035 
0xffffff801d357b50 : 0xffffff801d5d5803 
0xffffff801d357ba0 : 0xffffff801d425a60 
0xffffff801d357bc0 : 0xffffff801d4863cd 
0xffffff801d357ce0 : 0xffffff801d485b86 
0xffffff801d357d40 : 0xffffff801dd16409 
0xffffff801d357db0 : 0xffffff801d5d68b7 
0xffffff801d357ec0 : 0xffffff801dd1c57c 
0xffffff801d357ed0 : 0xffffff801d4262bf 
0xffffffd0962e3a00 : 0xffffff801d4ec2e0 
0xffffffd0962e3a90 : 0xffffff80203bd84d 
0xffffffd0962e3ab0 : 0xffffff80203c2b84 
0xffffffd0962e3b00 : 0xffffff80203cfdd3 
0xffffffd0962e3cd0 : 0xffffff801ed9db20 
0xffffffd0962e3ee0 : 0xffffff801ed9d849 
0xffffffd0962e3f20 : 0xffffff801dc574ae 
0xffffffd0962e3f60 : 0xffffff801dc56ad7 
0xffffffd0962e3fa0 : 0xffffff801d42518e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon(1.0)[19E24D70-253E-347A-B633-72FC9C96A1F8]@0xffffff801ed9b000->0xffffff801ed9efff
         com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily(1.2)[B78215CE-B379-3406-9BEF-1DA069A1FAFB]@0xffffff8020362000->0xffffff80203f3fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController(1.0)[CC54EDB6-85C9-3C42-8F9F-CF9BEBB8EDEE]@0xffffff801e891000->0xffffff801e894fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[4174C698-A692-3609-94C7-453B6CEB337D]@0xffffff801ec29000->0xffffff801ec41fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon(1.0)[19E24D70-253E-347A-B633-72FC9C96A1F8]@0xffffff801ed9b000->0xffffff801ed9efff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties(1.2)[087D9D35-1AA3-35E2-B9FE-BEE6A1D9A61C]@0xffffff8020466000->0xffffff8020466fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[9AAF8737-B8CD-3A43-A654-69FD563A54CA]@0xffffff801fb40000->0xffffff801fb41fff
Process name corresponding to current thread (0xffffff869574e540): kernel_task
Mac OS version:
21D49
Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 21.3.0: Wed Jan  5 21:37:58 PST 2022; root:xnu-8019.80.24~20/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 93729D02-FE6F-355B-BA76-BA930AA7103F
KernelCache slide: 0x000000001d200000
KernelCache base:  0xffffff801d400000
Kernel slide:      0x000000001d210000
Kernel text base:  0xffffff801d410000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801d300000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)
Hibernation exit count: 0
System uptime in nanoseconds: 47455813288
Last Sleep:           absolute           base_tsc          base_nano
Uptime  : 0x0000000b0c9663fd
Sleep   : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
Wake    : 0x0000000000000000 0x0000001309d1ed00 0x0000000000000000
Zone info:
Foreign   : 0xffffff8021e76000 - 0xffffff8021e83000
Native    : 0xffffff802e9c9000 - 0xffffffa02e9c9000
Readonly  : 0xffffff84fb695000 - 0xffffff8695029000
Metadata  : 0xffffffd55ab92000 - 0xffffffd57ac5e000
Bitmaps   : 0xffffffd57ac5e000 - 0xffffffd57dc5e000
last started kext at 33784720187: >driverkit.serial 6.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7fb6727000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:

!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
AudioAUUC  1.70
!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
AGPM   127
X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@fileutil   20.036.15
!AHDAHardwareConfigDriver  283.15
!AHDA  283.15
!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 6.4.12
eficheck   1
!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   6.4.12
!ALPC  3.1
pmtelemetry    1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
usb.!UUserHCI  1
!AHV   1
!ADiskImages2  126.60.3
!A!IBDWGraphics    18.0.4
AGDCBacklightControl   6.4.12
!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 18.0.4
!ABacklight    180.4
!AMCCSControl  1.14
!AThunderboltIP    4.0.3
!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
!ASMCLMU   212
!ACameraInterface  7.8.1
ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
@UVCService 1
|SCSITaskUserClient 452.60.2
!UCardReader   532.40.7
!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.tmpfs  1
@filesystems.lifs   1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   582.60.2
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@filesystems.apfs   1933.80.3
AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
!AAHCIPort 351
!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    5020.1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
!ARTC  2.0.1
!AACPIButtons  6.1
!AHPET 1.8
!ASMBIOS   2.1
!AACPIEC   6.1
!AAPIC 1.7
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
@nke.applicationfirewall    402
|IOKitRegistryCompatibility 1
|EndpointSecurity   1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
@kec.!AEncryptedArchive 1
driverkit.serial   6.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
@kext.triggers  1.0
DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
!AGraphicsControl  6.4.12
!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IO!BSerialManager  9.0.0
|IO!BPacketLogger   9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    9.0.0
|IO!BHost!CTransport    9.0.0
IO!BHost!CPCIeTransport    9.0.0
|IOAVB!F    1010.2
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    1000.11
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
|CSR!BHost!CUSBTransport    9.0.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   9.0.0
|Broadcom!B20703USBTransport    9.0.0
!AIPAppender   1.0
!UAudio    414.7
|IOAudio!F  300.10
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
!AAudioClockLibs   100.9.1
|IOAccelerator!F2   462.4.1
!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  593
!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
!AThunderboltEDMSink   5.0.3
!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  8.5.1
@!AGPUWrangler  6.4.12
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    6.4.12
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
|IOGraphics!F   593
!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
usb.cdc    5.0.0
usb.networking 5.0.0
usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
usb.!UHub  1.2
!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   8.5.1
!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   8.5.1
!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    4.1.1
!ABSDKextStarter   3
|IOSurface  302.11.1
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAHCIBlock!S  333
!AActuatorDriver   5430.21
!AThunderboltNHI   7.2.8
|IOThunderbolt!F    9.3.3
|IO80211!FLegacy    1200.12.2b1
|IOSkywalk!F    1.0
mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
corecapture    1.0.4
|IOAHCI!F   295
!AHIDKeyboard  228
!AMultitouchDriver 5430.21
!AInputDeviceSupport   5400.30
!AHS!BDriver   5020.1
IO!BHIDDriver  9.0.0
!AHSSPIHIDDriver   63
usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
!AHSSPISupport 63
!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
usb.!UXHCI 1.2
!AEFINVRAM 2.1
!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
|IOTimeSync!F   1000.11
|IONetworking!F 3.4
DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 9.0.0
|IOReport!F 47
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
!ASSE  1.0
!AKeyStore 2
!UTDM  532.40.7
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  209.40.6
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  452.60.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  452.60.2
!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
$!AImage4   4.2.0
@kext.CoreTrust 1
!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
!AEffaceable!S 1.0
!ACredentialManager    1.0
KernelRelayHost    1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
usb.!UCommon   1.0
!ABusPower!C   1.0
!ASEPManager   1.0.1
IOSlaveProcessor   1
!AACPIPlatform 6.1
!ASMC  3.1.9
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
watchdog   1
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 12.0
```

Before I go too far and, I dunno, buy a new MBP, any ideas or thoughts on why this might be happening would be appreciated. I prefer to try and fix these things on my own and I'm stumped at this point. I did just send it in about a year ago to get the battery replaced.

Thanks,

andy

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, I had a matching panic which I attributed to a marginal CPU, details [here](https://www.stix.id.au/wiki/macOS_mp_kdp_enter()_system_crash). It would manage to panic without anything attached, though.

TL;DR: during another crash, the kernel debugger is attempting to halt other processors via an NMI IPI, and getting a time out from one particular core (cpu 3 above). Afaik, Non-Maskable-Interrupt Inter-Processor-Interrupt should never time out unless there's something wrong with the CPU.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/320651)

Comment: Should I have just said "Your CPU is faulty"? I guess that's what I tried to say - "marginal" in this sense means perturbations in eg. thermal, power, etc appears to cause the CPU to fail. There should never be a time out on an NMI IPI.